# How to create a struct for Span<byte>

Tags: c#, struct

I am trying to create a `Struct` of the Type `Span<byte>` but I get a compiler error for this line:
`public Span<byte> X { get; set; }`

It says:
***Field or auto-implemented property cannot be of type `Span<byte>` unless it is an instance member of a ref struct.***

I am not sure what this means or how I can create a struct of `Span<byte>`. I know `structs` are very fast so this is the reason I try to use both `Span` and `Structs` together.
Thank you!

```
    public struct SpanStruct
    {
        public Span<byte> X { get; set; }
        public SpanStruct(Span<byte> x)
        {
            X = x;
        }
    }
    void function1()
    {
        var list = new SpanStruct[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Span<byte> span = new Span<byte>();
            list[i] = new SpanStruct(span);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say you want a struct but you've defined a class. I believe the only added requirement is that you define it as a [ref struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-struct-types) which restricts its use to only stack allocations. However you won't be able to store these structs in an array like that since the array lives on the heap. You could however use `stackalloc` to create a stack allocated array accessed via a pointer.

Comment: @Mike I changed to `struct` I did a mistake there. Okay that is interesting with the `stackalloc` and a pointer. The thing is that I will store a very big memory(that never change) that will be accessed by many functions and sent along to many functions. So by doing this as you mentioned with a pointer. It should be a very fast/efficient way to move around this memory to say 20 functions in approx: 3 seconds?

Comment: If the memory doesn't change and is a single thing don't worry about `stackalloc` instead just use a normal array and `Memory` if you want a way to refer to only a portion of the array. `stackalloc` is about many short lived (and typically small to medium size) things whose creation and deletion on the heap causes memory pressure.

Comment: @Andreas I would not take the use of unsafe code lightly. `stackalloc` means what it says on the label. It is stack allocated memory and a stack is typically 1 MB. Does your "big memory" fit in 1 MB? If not stack allocated memory is not what you want to use. It sounds like you are unfamiliar with some of these concepts and you are attracted by Span/Struct because you hear they are "very fast". They can be fast if you are expert using them correctly in certain scenarios. Otherwise I would stick to safer alternatives.

Comment: Yes this was interesting facts to know. I should not use `stackalloc` then. The memory could be very very large. Up to 100 MB or more actually. A normal `array` should then work and perheps just pass around a pointer to that memory in a way. I use `Vectors` and `pointers` so I am already stuck to use the `unsafe` code for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Span` is a special type that is designed to live on the stack. You cannot put it inside of a `class` because that could make what it references not outlive the heap reference. For instance you can use a `Span` to refer to something that is created via `stackalloc`.

Typically `Span` is only used as a local variable to refer to a piece of data in the most abstract way possible. There are instances where it makes sense to store them but in a lot of those cases `Memory` is better because while it removes the ability to refer to things like `stackalloc` you likely don't want that ability if you are storing things in classes.

If you need to create a `struct` that contains a `Span` denote it with `public ref struct SpanStruct` but note that means it too can not be put in a `class`.

Comment: That was interesting. So I can't use `ref struct` in the way I wanted it with `Span`. The reason I wanted to use it is that it seems very fast to dispose on the `Heap`. Should `Memory` work instead and be as fast to work/dispose?

Comment: @Andreas: I don't know what you mean by very fast to dispose. `Span` is non-owning.

Comment: I am not entirely sure either. I have just seen a video where they showed benchmark with `class` vs `struct` and it difference was that the `class` was 111 ms and the `struct` was 6 ms and described that it was because `disposing` a struct on the heap was extremely fast because only one thing was needed in order to delete/dispose all the memory that existed in the `struct` (I think it was about the `struct` itself as such)

Comment: @Andreas: You should look at the number of iterations they did to get that big of a difference. For most code `struct` vs `class` is about the kind of data it is and things like `Span` are advanced tools you pull out when you have seen performance problems in your code.

Comment: It was 1,000,000 iterations in that test. But perheps as you say. I will anyway only need one big `array` and perheps a `pointer` to that memory so that should work for the big memory(100 MB) that I pass around I beleive and be fast enough to use and dispose?

Comment: It also cannot be used in lambdas, which blocks its usage in an important set of features like high order functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is the language that restricts that we cannot use it as field or property because `Span<T>` can only live on the stack. When should we use it?

It can be only used as following:

- Method Parameter
- A return type of a method
- A local variable

See the following [post](http://www.devsanon.com/c/c-7-2-introducing-ref-struct/)

From Microsoft docs:

> Span is a ref struct that is allocated on the stack rather than on the managed heap. Ref struct types have a number of restrictions to ensure that they cannot be promoted to the managed heap, including that they can't be boxed

Comment: If you declare a `ref struct` you can use it as a field of a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

> Span is a ref struct that is allocated on the stack rather than on the managed heap. Ref struct types have a number of restrictions to ensure that they cannot be promoted to the managed heap, including that they can't be boxed, they can't be assigned to variables of type Object, dynamic or to any interface type, they can't be fields in a reference type, and they can't be used across await and yield boundaries. In addition, calls to two methods, Equals(Object) and GetHashCode, throw a NotSupportedException.

This is from Microsoft documentation.
You're trying to use `Span<T>` as a field/property within a reference type - `class SpanStruct` - which violates this.